# My react webapp is not showing any styling despite compiling successfully

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to build an app using React, according to VCS, the app complies successfully, however I cannot see any of my styling or the text of my div on the webpage. I'm following a youtube tutorial please see link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2HvISWe9ArM&list=PL5JH4SeiwEwxQ6FwmZLrutvdznN6xrem-. Around the 41:44 minute is where things start going wrong.

App.js

```js
import React from "react";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="w-screen h-screen bg-blue-400 flex justify-center items-center text-base font-bold">
      App
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

index.js

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react";

import "./index.css";
import App from "./App.js";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root">
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

index.css

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Comment: make sure the path is correct to your index.css when you try to import it from index.js, "./" suggest index.css and index.js are in the same folder, usually in the src folder

Comment: @hugomztl, I've doubled checked and the path is correct